# Comparing a selected range of indexes to a threshold

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, indexing, sapply

I want to compare all scores in a certain range (from i until the index that belongs to the range of i) to the last baseline score, and update the baseline score in a recursive way. The range is based on the corresponding index that meets the minimal time difference required to be able to confirm a new baseline.
If all scores in this range are lower than the last baseline score, then I want the new baseline to become the highest value of all scores in the range (ie, the closest to the old baseline).

```
df <- tibble(
i = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"),
range_index = c("2", "4", "4", "5", "7", "7", "9", "9", "NA"),
score = c("5", "4", "4", "3", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1"))
```

I am looking to do something like this in sapply or a for loop:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(
baseline = first(score),
baseline = sapply(1:n(), function(i) {
  if (all(score[i]:score[range_index[i]]) < baseline[i-1]) {return(max(score[i]:score[range_index[i]]))}
  else {return(baseline[i-1])}}))
```

But I think score[i]:score[range[i]] doesn't compare all scores to the last baseline. How can I create a condition that is true if each of these scores are lower than the last baseline?

The desired outcome is:

```
baseline = c("5", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1")
```

Explanation: the first baseline is 5. At i=2 the new baseline is set to 4, as all scores between i=2 and i=4 (corresponding range) are lower than 5. The new baseline is 4, and not 3, because 4 is the greatest score out of i=2 until i=4.
At i=4 we obtain the new baseline 3, because all scores in the range (score[4]=3, score[5]=2) are lower than the last baseline, which was 4.
At i=5, we don't obtain a new baseline despite the decrease, because the range includes i=7, and score[7] (==3) is not lower than the last baseline (==3).
The new baseline at i=8 is obtained as all scores i[8:9] are lower than the last baseline of 3.

Comment: A couple things that will help someone help you: 1) Make your code snippet reproducible. (I should be able to run it just by copying and pasting. Currently, there are several missing end brackets and `score` and `range` are not defined.) 2) After `score` and `range` are defined, please provide the expected result. That will help demonstrate what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question @jblood94 I hope this clarifies it!

Comment: Please extend your example by some more, say 5, values.

Comment: It appears that `range_index` (and possibly `score`) should be `numeric` instead of `character`. I admit I am having a hard time interpreting the desired result even with the example. Can you explain in words how you arrive at the desired outcome? (E.g., "the last value is `2` because ...").

Comment: I have extended the example with more values and have provided an explanation with the desired output, hopefully this helps @jblood94

Comment: I have extended the example @Friede

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's best to iterate with a `for` loop.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(id = rep(1:2, each = 9),
             range_index = rep(c(2,4,4,5,7,7,9,9,NA), 2),
             score = c(5,4,4,3,2,2,3,1,1,5,4,4,3,2,2,3,1,0))
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    baseline = {
      baseline <- score
      for (i in 2:(n() - 1)) {
        baseline[i] <- min(baseline[i - 1], max(score[i]:score[range_index[i]]))
      }
      baseline[n()] <- baseline[n() - 1]
      baseline
    }
  )
#> # A tibble: 18 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>       id range_index score baseline
#>    <int>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1           2     5        5
#>  2     1           4     4        4
#>  3     1           4     4        4
#>  4     1           5     3        3
#>  5     1           7     2        3
#>  6     1           7     2        3
#>  7     1           9     3        3
#>  8     1           9     1        1
#>  9     1          NA     1        1
#> 10     2           2     5        5
#> 11     2           4     4        4
#> 12     2           4     4        4
#> 13     2           5     3        3
#> 14     2           7     2        3
#> 15     2           7     2        3
#> 16     2           9     3        3
#> 17     2           9     1        1
#> 18     2          NA     0        1
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! Just some last doubts:
- This example is the sequence of scores for a single subject, but in reality I have many patients so I would want to execute this loop separately for each subject ID (so that the baseline of subject 1 is not used to calculate the baseline for subject 2). 
Is it possible to execute a loop by group like that?
- The last time point does not have a range index because there is no date after this, so this index cannot result in a new baseline. However, the loop gives an error if range_index=NA. How can I deal with that?
Thanks again!

Comment: If it's `tidyverse`, do `group_by` on ID with the `mutate`.

Comment: I would have though you would replace `NA` with the row index, so that the range included only that one index, but you say the last index "cannot result in a new baseline". If that's the case, then do the loop as `for (i in 2:(nrow(df) - 1)` and do `baseline[length(score)] <- baseline[length(score) - 1]` after the loop. To clarify what you want, what would be the final baseline value in your example if the last score equals 0 instead of 1?

Comment: If the last score equals 0, the final baseline would still be 1 as the decrease to 0 could not be confirmed with a following time point. Your suggestion seems to do the trick! 
I know how `group_by` works, but here the loop doesn't seem to take the groups in the df into account after I added `group_by(ID)` to the df. The baseline variable is not created as a new variable using `mutate`, but it is only giving output. Is there a way to incorporate the loop into a `mutate` statement (that I can then `group_by` beforehand?)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is a solution I was looking for. Appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Using `purrr::accumulate2`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(baseline = accumulate2(
    i,
    replace_na(range_index, max(i)),
    \(b, i, r) min(b, max(score[i:r])),
    .init = score[[1]]
  )[-1])
```

Result:

```
  i range_index score baseline
1 1           2     5        5
2 2           4     4        4
3 3           4     4        4
4 4           5     3        3
5 5           7     2        3
6 6           7     2        3
7 7           9     3        3
8 8           9     1        1
9 9        <NA>     1        1
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you for sharing your insight and the working code! I am not familiar with using `accumulate2`, but just for my understanding: am I correct that in `(b, i, r)`, _b_ refers to the last baseline value, _i_ refers to the current index, and _r_ refers to the range_index?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. [`accumulate()` and `accumulate2()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/accumulate.html) are useful for problems where each step depends on the results of the prior step — ie, in your case, the previous `baseline` value.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question of how to compare a selected range of indexes `[i:j]` to a threshold, this can be done using the minimum value or maximum value of this range to the threshold: `min(score[i:j]) > threshold[i]` (if all scores need to be greater than the threshold) or `max(score[i:j]) < threshold[i]` (if all scores need to be lower than the threshold)